# Using "array" environment with a specific font size

Tags: fontsize, arrays

Can we determine font size of a specific array? I am preparing presentation and I want to use different font sizes for different arrays

```
\begin{array}{l}"FONT SIZE COMMAND"
bla bla bla
\end{array}

\begin{array} "DIFFERENT FONT SIZE"
bla bla bla
\end{array}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please, extend your code snippets to one complete but small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending by `\end{document}˙that we can see context of use of yours arrays. changing font size should be done before `array`.

Comment: It is impossible to tell from fragments what you mean. If the arrays are in separate math expressions simply put `\large`  or `\small` etc before the math starts. if they are in the same expression latex doesn't allow size changes but if you _really_ need it you could use a nested `\mbox{\large$....`

Comment: Instead of font sizes, math support 4 styles: \displaystyle, \textstyle, \scriptstyle and \scriptscriptstyle.  IIRC, the default for array is \textstyle, not \displaystyle.